# Mysql datetime different in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime

I post here today because I encounter a problem storing a Datetime in mysql with Javascript. The datetime I store, and I can see in Phpmyadmin is not the same as the datetime I got with a query (Select)

I think this is a timezone related problem, but I don't know how to solve this. I tried to save time in UTC with

```
UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

But I still don't get the right datetime.

I store the datetime with :

```
connection.query("UPDATE `users` SET `last_disconnect` = now() WHERE `users`.`uuid` = ?", [userId])
```

(I tried to create a new Javascript date and store it but it's the same)

Here is the datetime stored (the datetime I can see in Phpmyadmin) :

```
2019-06-04 21:19:39
```

Here is my query :

```
connection.query("SELECT last_disconnect FROM users WHERE uuid=?", [userId])
```

Here is what I got with the query :

```
2019-06-04T20:19:39.000Z
```

Here is what I got when I create a new date with this :

```
console.log(new Date(dateFromRequest))
```

->

```
Tue Jun 04 2019 22:19:39 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
```

The datetime I want to get in Javascript is the datetime stored in Mysql :

```
2019-06-04 21:19:39
```

My time zone is GMT +2

When I check the datetime in Mysql it says Timezone +0200

Does someone know what is wrong with what I am doing ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysqljs - Connection options#dateStrings](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options)

Execute **query** without **dateStrings**

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM user', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results[0].registerDate)
});
```

**Output**

```
_> node index.js
2018-06-04T20:13:17.000Z
```

---

Execute **same query** but with **dateStrings**

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'test',
    dateStrings: true // yo, im here
});
```

**Output**

```
_> node index.js
2018-06-04 23:13:17
```

---

### Simple example

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM user', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    results.map(x => {
        const date = new Date(x.registerDate);
        console.log(date.getFullYear())
    })
});
```

**Output**

```
_> node index.js
2018
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's perfect :) I didn't think there were an option like this I should have searched for it